# Storing a dynamic variable for Workflow in SPD 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, string

I am new to Share Point designer 2013. I would like to Store a value to a variable as follows:

Store 'field' in 'Variable'.

When compared in SPD 2007, there is "Build Dynamic String" under Actions. But in SPD 2013 there is no "Build Dynamic String" under Actions .

Also I need to know what workflow can be used for 'Stop Workflow' in SPD 2013.

Could you please help me to find a solution for the same?

Answer (score 3):

We can store the field values into a workflow variable.

For that first we need to create a variable and then assign values into it.

**1.** Create a workflow variable: From the ribbon you can select local variables and create as shown in below image.

[image: Create Local variable]

**2.** Assign values to variable: From actions menu we need to select an OOB action `Set Workflow Variable` which allow us to set variable values. Refer below mage

[image]

**3.** Set values: Now once you have an action in your stage, click on `workflow variable link` a drop down with an option of your variable will open, select it. Then click on `value link`, a pop up will open from which you select field of current item.

**-----UPDATE-----**

Well to create a dynamic string we still use the set variable action, I guess this `Build Dynamic String` action is not available in 2013 SPD.

To set any dynamic string in a variable refer the below screen shots

**1.** So first add action `set workflow variable` and click on `value` link

[image]

**2.** you will see the similar string builder which was in 2007SPD and here you concatenate string with a combination your own prefix or suffix with a current item value.

[image]

Once you get the value in variable, you can use this variable any where in your workflow.

**---Update to end workflow--------**

The 2013 workflows are developed based on different stages. If you need to end a workflow at a particular condition then you can. follow below steps.

- In a stage find block `Transition to stage`
- Place a focus and from `actions` select go to stage
- Click on a link `a stage`
- A drop down with `all available stages` and `End of workflow` will open
- Select `End of workflow`

Comment: Hi Asad, Not this exactly. In SPD 2007, Under actions I could find an action 'Store "dynamic string" in "variable"'. I would like to know whether we have exactly same Workflow in SPD 2013. Could you please let me know what is the Workflow for the same or let me know if any alternate Workflow .

Comment: What would you like to store in a dynamic string? example a combination of current item and some prefix or something similar?

Comment: Yes I would like to Store combination of current item

Comment: Based on my knowledge I don't think so in 2013 designer we have "Build Dynamic String" Action. But this Set variable action does the job of making dynamic string, like concatenating. refer my updated answer.

Comment: okay.. Thank you . I will try the same. Also would like to know what is the alternate for Stop Workflow in SPD 2013

Comment: Hi Sophia, If you are using 2013 workflow templates, then I guess ending workflow is possible in stages. Read my last update in answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an action in SPD Workflow available in both 2010 and 2013 version

> Set Workflow Variable

This will store a field value in variable. The variable value would be updated if the field value updates. With this action you can even build strings.

**Stop Workflow** action is no more available in SPD 2013 workflow. This action is deprecated in 2013.

Comment: Do we have an alternative for Stop Workflow?